# Application Design - Menu system

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewcontroller that has a UITableView and and a couple of buttons, (add and done)

When the user clicks add I need to get some details (which represent a notification they are setting in the app).

Details like notification name, a number, target score etc...

What is the best way to get this info, is it a good idea to use a UIView and animate it onto the screen with some textfields or something like that?

Any good cocoa controls you can recommend?

Problem is my app already transitions from the rootview controller to the notification input controller modally, I was trying to get a simple UI to just enter data, I could use UIAlertViews but they are so ugly....

Comment: I would think you'd want a Modal View.

Comment: Problem is my app already transitions from the rootview controller to the notification input controller modally, I was trying to get a simple UI to just enter data, I could use UIAlertViews but they are so ugly....

Comment: Nothing preventing you from having a hierarchy of modal views. So not sure of the issue if notification input controller was presented modally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your comment above:

```
    CustomUIView *inputView = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offscreenRect)];
    inputView.alpha = 0;
    self.notificationInputController.userInactionEnabled = NO;


            [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                             animations:^{
                                 inputView.alpha = 1;
                                 inputView.rect = CGRectMake(onScreenRect);
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.notificationInputController addSubView:inputView];
    self.notificationInputController.userInactionEnabled = YES;
                                 }];
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, so it doesn't break any design rules to use a UIView as a base for an input menu? ie. I don't always have to use a full viewcontroller for such things?

Comment: I don't see how you'd be braking any rules. If there's something I'm missing please add a comment and we can re-adjust.

Comment: I went with a nice uiview, animated in and out with text fields. And dimmed the controls below- thanks for the help again!